# adding numbers without grep -c option

Tags: bash, command-line

I have a txt file like

```
Peugeot:406:1999:Silver:1
Ford:Fiesta:1995:Red:2
Peugeot:206:2000:Black:1
Ford:Fiesta:1995:Red:2
```

I am looking for a command That counts the number of red Ford Fiesta cars.
The last number in each line is the amount of that particular car.
The command I am looking for CANNOT use the -c option of grep.

so this command should just output the number 4.

Any help would be welcome, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple bit of awk would do the trick:

```
awk -F: '$1=="Ford" && $4=="Red" { c+=$5 } END { print c }' file
```

Output:

```
4
```

Explanation:

The `-F:` switch means that the input field separator is a colon, so the car manufacturer is `$1` (the 1st field), the model is `$2`, etc.

If the 1st field is "Ford" and the 4th field is "Red", then add the value of the 5th (last) field to the variable `c`. Once the whole file has been processed, print out the value of `c`.

---

For a native bash solution:

```
c=0
while IFS=":" read -ra col; do 
    [[ ${col[0]} == Ford ]] && [[ ${col[3]} == Red ]] && (( c += col[4] ))
done < file && echo $c
```

Effectively applies the same logic as the awk one above, without any additional dependencies.

Comment: Nice bash solution, nicer than mine :)

Comment: Thanks, also how would you just count the number lines with Red, Ford, and Fiesta?

Comment: @user3430741 I would hope that my existing explanation is clear enough for you to be able to extend what I've done. If it isn't, please let me know what doesn't make sense. Either way, I encourage you to give it a try yourself using either approach and by all means let me know if you get stuck. It's basically a simple case of adding another condition to the ones that are already there.

Answer (score 1):

Methods:

1.) use some scripting language for counting, like `awk` or `perl` and such. Awk solution already posted, here is an perl solution.

```
perl -F: -lane '$s+=$F[4] if m/Ford:.*:Red/}{print $s' < carfile
#or
perl -F: -lane '$s+=$F[4] if ($F[0]=~m/Ford/ && $F[3]=~/Red/)}{print $s' < carfile
```

both examples prints

```
4
```

2.) The second method is based on shell-pipelining

- filter out the right rows
- extract the column with the count
- sum the numbers

e.g some examples:

```
grep 'Ford:.*:Red:' carfile | cut -d: -f5 | paste -sd+ | bc
```

- the `grep` filter out the right rows
- the `cut` get the last column
- the `paste` creates an line like `2+2` what can be counted by
- the `bc` for counting

Another example:

```
sed -n 's/\(Ford:.*:Red\):\(.*\)/\2/p' carfile | paste -sd+ | bc
```

- the `sed` filter and extract

another example - different way of counting

```
(echo 0 ; sed -n 's/\(Ford:.*:Red\):\(.*\)/\2+/p' carfile ;echo p )| dc
```

- numbers are counted by RPN calculator called `dc`, e.g. it works like `0 2 +` - first comes the values and as the last the operation.
- the first echo puts into the stack `0`
- the sed creates a stream of numbers like `2+` `2+`
- the last echo `p` prints the stack

exists many other possibilies how count a strem of numbers.

e.g counting by `bash`

```
while read -r num
do
   sum=$(( $sum + $num ))
done < <(sed -n 's/\(Ford:.*:Red\):\(.*\)/\2/p' carfile)
```

and pure bash:

```
while IFS=: read -r maker model year color count
do
    if [[ "$maker" == "Ford" && "$color" == "Red" ]]
    then
        (( sum += $count ))
    fi
done < carfile
echo $sum
```